# In the Eclipse debugger, how can I view any primitive long value as a formatted date?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, timestamp, long-integer

I'm currently working on a Java application that frequently uses primitive long values for timestamps. It would be great if I could see these in the Eclipse debugger as both a long value and a formatted timestamp. Perhaps if the number is out of range for any reasonable timestamp, it would only appear as a number. The "Detail Formatters" section of Eclipse Preferences offers nothing for primitives, at least not that I can find. Watch expressions are not much good, because it requires making a new watch expression for each and every class having a primitive long timestamp--not worth the labor. Does anyone know of another way to generically view any long value as a formatted timestamp? Thanks for your help.

Byron

Answer (score 1):

The best solution may be to change the application so that it uses `Date` objects instead. Those are basically nothing but a thing wrapper around a `long` that gives it the semantics of a timestamp. The problems you're having are the direct result of not having such semantics, and nobody though of implementing a way to add them to all `long` values because those generally *aren't* all timestamps.

Comment: The reason we don't use java.util.Date (or any timestamp wrapper) is that we have a cache with limited memory allocation that is full of objects having timestamps all over them. It's much more space efficient to use primitive longs, and we don't need any date or time related methods for the timestamps because all related processing is done by pluggable algorithms. I really wish Eclipse would just offer simple BeanShell hooks for every standard view. BeanShell is a slow performer, but Eclipse is already so slow it couldn't possibly be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your [own formatter](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/tips-and-tricks-debugging-ecli) to transform any value/object:

[image]

with:

[image]

into any presentation you want:

[image]

---

As the OP [Byron Hawkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351410/byron-hawkins) comments, it is an effort, but which can be associated to a class (and not a variable during debug like a watch expression), as [illustrated here](http://www.certpal.com/blogs/2009/09/eclipse-tips-and-tricks-part-2/):

[image]

So it will be valid for any variable/instances of that type.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is roughly the same amount of work as adding a watch expression for each object. It persists better than watch expressions, but still constitutes a huge effort.